# an object is an instance of a class. what does that mean.?

Tags: java

An object is an instance of a class What does that means I never understand this phrase properly.Give me some real world examples.I am bit confused.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you read the Wikipedia article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_%28computer_science%29 This issue is discussed in detail in a large number of resources; it is only a matter of locating one that helps you make sense of it. Additionally, the subject of this question isn't really a good fit for StackOverflow. StackOverflow is more geared toward specific programming issues. You would need to refine this question first, but if you could narrow down your confusion and make it more specific, this might be a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: cool got it....but the wiki link you had given me is not verified.

Comment: Also, don't get super bogged down in the concept of a class vs. an instance. What's really valuable is knowing how to leverage those concepts to write clean, maintainable code.

Comment: k.but the wiki link you had given me is not verified and not trust worthy,,,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Human is a class. You are an instance of Human.

Comment: I'd say human is an interface, but your answer is cool. :)

Comment: That is next topic, once classes and instances are understood :)

Comment: and Human DNA is the Abstract class?

Comment: I'd say bytes are DNA

Comment: I wanted to say this!

Comment: Now I got it clearly.

Comment: @sandy7094 I know it is a trivial answer, but it really comes down to it and I always use it as an example for questions like yours. Great if it helped you.